# Full factorial repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, fractional-factorial

I have a Full factorial design where factor1 has 2 levels and factor2 has 5 levels fully crossed (10 treatments in total). Then the samples are collected from same individuals (plots) at 6 different times.

My question is if I run a repeated measures anova using 6 times, what is the best way to interpret the results? Specifically in terms of graphs, what would be the best way to show the graphs the effect of factor1 and factor2 and time and their interactions?

Thanks

Comment: For each factor, plots of level means.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you very much for your prompt response.